# append more than one value in single row using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called user having 3 columns namely id, name and phone no.

i want insert data like below clip.

```
+----+---------------+---------------------+-     
| id | name          | phone no            |      
+----+---------------+---------------------+-     
| 1  |  mahadev      |   +91 XXXXX         |      
| 2  |  swamy        |   +91 YYYYY         |      
|    |               |   +91 ZZZZZ         |      
| 3  |  charlie      |   +91 AAAAA         |      
|    |               |                     |      
+----+---------------+---------------------+-
```

Here question is how can i add more than one values (one by one) to same row as showing id = 2 in above clip.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create an array of values and separate it with implode() and insert

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you intended, how you intended. And for a reason.

One possible solution (bad), would be to make id non-unique and then insert two times id 2, name swamy, phone for two different phones.

Proper solution is to have two tables. One is your current `user`, which would have only `id` and `name`.

Second table is `phone_numbers` which would have `user_id` and `phone_no`. Primary key on that table would be composite of `user_id` and `phone_no` so it would prevent duplicates. Then in that table you can insert as many numbers as you need.

In your example you would have two rows with `user_id=2`, one for each phone number.

Then it is only a matter JOIN to join the two tables together and display your results.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Could you please let me know how can i join two table data so that, it should looks like id=2 in above clip.

Comment: Something like `SELECT users.id, users.name, phone_numbers.phone_no FROM users LEFT JOIN phone_numbers ON phone_numbers.user_id = users.id ORDER BY users.id ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be creating an array of that data and then storing it with `serialize()` function.

Small example:

```
$phones_array = array('phone_a' => '+91 YYYYY', 'phone_b' => '+91 ZZZZZ');

serialize($phones_array);
```

Now your data are serialized into a string, trying `var_dump($phones_array)` you should get:

```
string 'a:2:{s:7:"phone_a";s:9:"+91 YYYYY";s:7:"phone_b";s:9:"+91 ZZZZZ";}' (length=66)
```

You can now insert this value into your table

You can retrieve this data with:

```
unserialize($phones_array);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. if i insert serialized data to table it shows "array" in that phone no column it is not showing actual phone no.

Comment: I think I don't understand ... Using `serialize($phones_array)` you get a string back. Now you can store this string in your field. and when you need to use these serialized value you can obtain your array back with `$myPhonesArray = unserialize($yourSerializedData)`

Answer (score 0):

SQL architecture don't allow such things. You need to use more than one row or you can use more than one table with foreign keys. Or you can `serialize(phone no)` before you put it into mysql.

Comment: @ilpaijin : Please let me know the command to retrieve unserialize($phones_array);